# What do I do with DW_OP_call_frame_cfa

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, dwarf

I'm trying to calculate the locations of local variables inside a running program using libdwarf. I used to be able to do this by executing DW_OP_fbreg which would ultimately map to a register that would the frame base for that function. In the newer dwarf standard the frame base is DW_OP_call_frame_cfa. I can't seem to find any information that tells me how to execute DW_OP_call_frame_cfa and come back with a frame base location. There's a lot of references to a CFA table and who restores what registers but I don't know how to get at that information and how to apply it. Can someone fill in the gaps?

Answer (score 4):

`DW_OP_call_frame_cfa` means that you have to use the call frame information to compute the CFA; then push this on the expression stack.

See section 6.4 ("Call Frame Information") of the DWARF 4 standard for an explanation of this.  Essentially you must now read the `.debug_frame` section and decode it according to the rules described in 6.4.  This amounts to writing another interpreter for another little bytecode language; and possibly reusing the DWARF expression interpreter as well.

This opcode is basically a space optimization in DWARF.  Compilers were already emitting the call frame information, and this opcode lets them reuse it to compute variable locations as well.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense in principal. Can you tell me what function gets the instruction list? We have dwarf_loclist_n() and the like for location expressions, but I can't seem to find the equivalent for CFA. Does it use the same DW_OP* operation constants?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the libdwarf API, so I can't suggest anything there.  Anyway, no, it doesn't use the DW_OP_* operations, unless the CFA refers to a DWARF expression (which it can in some cases).

Comment: @TomTromey What is meant by "push this on the expression stack"?

Comment: DWARF expressions implement a simple stack machine.  The various operations may push values on the stack, or pop values from this stack.  `DW_OP_call_frame_cfa` is one such operation that pushes a value on the stack.